# What is the best way to encapsulate React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, web-component, shadow-dom

I am trying to **encapsulate a React application** in a **Web component's Shadow Root** or an **iFrame** to build a **widget** for a Chatbot messenger like Intercom widget.

I´m using:

```
React 16.8.6
Typescript 3.5.3
Redux 4.0.4 
Styled-components 4.3.2 
Material-UI 4.3.3
```

I based my Web component choice on [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/web-components.html) React official doc *(that didint mention any of my issue)*.

First, I encountered some **style issue**, with both styled-components and Material-UI, because they both put their styles in the light DOM header. But, **I figured out how to deal with both** issues (I can help anyone with the same problems). [SOLVED]

Then my components are rendered without a problem, but **events are not working**, After some research I found that when you render a react component inside Shadow DOM events will not be dispatched to react. I.e. when a user clicks on your react component nothing happens. so i used [this](https://github.com/spring-media/react-shadow-dom-retarget-events) repo to fix this issue and **retarget and dispatch events** to React. [PARTIALLY-SOLVED]

But unfortunately, this is not enough, because some events like `onChange` don't get fixed, and some depth like Material-UI add their own events, The problem is in React it self check this [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10422) and they are not so motivated to fix it in a near date.[ISSUE]

So I decided to **move to another encapsulation alternative**, the **iFrame**. I didn't find a helpful tuto, repo or thread yet and all existing npm modules aren't updated neither optimized for Typescript.
I need a clear way to encapsulate my app in the `#document` of the `iFrame`.

Please, propose a repo. or give me any idea of implementation, any idea could be very helpful.

Comment: I don't see why an IFRAME wouldn't work? Did you remove all the other _stuff_ you added once you switched to using an IFRAME (i.e. all those event redirections should not be required). An IFRAME is very much like a separate window. Also when using an IFRAME you should be able to test your REACT in a separate window to make sure it works on its own.

Comment: @AlexisWilke First, I naively tried to put my app inside a native HTML frame, but the app renders just beside the `#document`, so no encapsulation are gained. then I tried a bunch of old and not maintained repositories from npm and github, but I didn't succeed to run any of them with Typscript.

Comment: @AlexisWilke and of course i removed all web component’s stuffs..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I did encapsulate my app in the `#document` of the `iframe` successfully.

```
// Create iframe.
const iFrame: any = document.createElement("iframe")
document.body.appendChild(iFrame)
// Create react entry point.
const mountPoint = document.createElement("div")
iFrame.contentWindow.document.body.appendChild(mountPoint)
ReactDOM.render(<App />, mountPoint)
```

I just forgot to point on the `x.contentWindow.document.body` element, instead, I pointed directly on the `iframe`.